# how to search in eclipse inside the documentation of local java/android/j2me

Tags: java, android, eclipse, helper

I want to get information about selected text when I press F1. But always it returns information about to using eclipse. You can look at the screen capture below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the kingori's answer I visited the [help.eclipse.org](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-export-javadoc.htm) link and found this shortcut:

`Open Attached Javadoc in a Browser (Shift+F2) => Opens the attached javadoc of current input of the Javadoc view in a browser.`

When you selected some text in editor, you can get access to the resource by clicking `Shift + F2` .

Answer (score 1):

You can't get API information by pressing F1, but you can use javadoc view in eclipse.

In Eclipse Help page( http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-javadoc.htm ) , see "Javadoc view" and "Open and configure external Javadoc documentation" secrtion.